# Starting point for 3D modeling program

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, 3d, rendering, modeling

I would like some assistance with a python 3D modeling program. I know this is a huge undertaking, but all I want is to know where to start, and any hurdles that I may have that I need to know about.

I have plenty of python experience, but not in 3D models or rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Blender for 3D modeling. Also, it has a Python API if you *need* to use Python

Comment: would i be able to have the python program have a rendered scene, along with extra features?

Comment: I'd recommend you check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/ and see if there are any questions there which help you

Answer (score 0):

You can consider about [Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/). Glass Engine is a rendering engine but not a modeling engine. With Glass Engine, you can load built models or assemble basic geometries together, define your own model by specify vertices and indices. The 3D viewport in Glass Engine is just a PyQt's QWidget, and you can layout it anywhere in your PyQt program. That means you can use all other features of GUI programing besides rendering.(but just in PyQt)

Install Glass Engine by `pip install glass-engine`. See full document at [Glass Engine Documentation](https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/)